# activeElement iframe with javafx

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

I have a problem. I'm developing with JavaFX and JavaScript, using the objetco webView. I have an iframe inside JavaFX container.I have an iframe within a JavaFX container and I'm trying to capture when a "click" occurs on an input component of the iframe.

With chrome console, the javascript code is ok, returns the expected value

My code is:

```
webView.addEventHandler(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED , new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(InputEvent event) {
        Element html = (Element) webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.activeElement.contentDocument.activeElement");

    }
});
```

Thx.

Comment: Really, `document.activeElement.document` works for you in the console? You'd think whatever element was focused didn't have a document of it's own, but who knows ?

Comment: Sorry, code is wrong.

my code is:

webView.addEventHandler(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED , new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(InputEvent event) {
        Element html = (Element) webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.activeElement.contentDocument.activeElement");

    }
});